# Canvas clipOutRect compatibility in AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, androidx, android-compatibility

I recently came across the deprecation of `clipRect(Rect,Region.Op)`, which I would like to use with `DIFFERENCE`. This was replaced with `clipOutRect(Rect)` and thus I implemented:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun clipOutRect(canvas: Canvas, rect: Rect) =
    if (SDK_INT >= O) canvas.clipOutRect(rect)
    else canvas.clipRect(rect, DIFFERENCE)
```

Now this looks like it could be a compatibility method in *AndroidX*, but for some reason I was not able to figure out, where I could find it exactly.

Is there a class already providing a compatibility method for `clipOutRect(Rect)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is - no. The only thing related to Canvas in AndroidX is this file: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/core/core-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/Canvas.kt

Long answer. 
First of all, `Canvas` is passed to view by native code, so it will be awkward to have something like `onDrawCompat(canvas: CanvasCompat)` in `ViewCompat` class. And I think there is no reason to do that at all.
Also, it's really not that type of deprecation you should worry about.
For example `WifiManager.startScan()` is noted with

> This method was deprecated in API level 28. The ability for apps to
>   trigger scan requests will be removed in a future release.

That says `Change this code now, or it will be broken year later`

That not the case with `clipRect`, it will be kept for backward compatibility with apps that won't be ever updated for years or even tenth of years. Deprecation warning for this is just like `Hey, we have new method with better functionality/name, if you target minimum is API 26 you can use that`